# error at javascript that connect to sql, asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql, countdown

I have javascript timer countdown with the code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "<% = TargetDate %>";
/*this is a property in code behind*/BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "the auction end"
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="countdown.js"></script>
</script>
```

the code behind:

```
public string TargetDate ()
{

    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); 
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Timer;Trusted_Connectopn=True"))
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    { 
        command.CommandText = "select * from endTime"; 
        connection.Open(); 
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
        dataTable.Load(reader); }
}
```

i get the error: 
't.TargetDate()': not all code paths return value.

when i tried to write return i got another error... what means that i dont know what to do :)

Answer (score 2):

Your method supposed to return string. It doesn't.

`public string TargetDate`

There is no `return`.

Use `ExecuteScalar`, instead of `ExecuteReader`.

Return the string value.

Answer (score 0):

You also have a spelling error in your connection string: `Trusted_Connectopn` should be `Trusted_Connection`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must return the targetdate value as string according to your function specification.
You should read the datatable and return that. Something like this

```
public string TargetDate ()
{
    String tDate = "";
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(); 
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=Timer;Trusted_Connection=True"))
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    { 
        command.CommandText = "select * from endTime"; 
        connection.Open(); 
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 
        dataTable.Load(reader);
         tDate = dataTable.Rows[0][0].toString(); // Expecting the first row and first column
 }
return tDate;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. i got error to the line: tDate = dataTable.rows[0][0];  // Expecting the first row and first column }return tDate;}

the error: 
CS1061: 'System.Data.DataTable' does not contain a definition for 'rows' and no extension method 'rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataTable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: thanks again. i editet the: tDate = dataTable.Rows[0][0].ToString();

now, there is other problem... at the aspx page, to the line: TargetDate = "<% = TargetDate %>";
  the error: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(char)' has some invalid arguments..... char ?! ... oh what a code.. what now ? :) thank you !